# Dim/Blur Background When SlidingDrawer Is Open

Tags: android, blur, slidingdrawer

I'm looking for a way to dim/blur background when the slidingdrawer is open but I couldn't find. Now, my question is, is it possible?

Comment: i am also playing with my app to make Dim/Blur/Transparent background in SlideMenu. can you please help me? i have also tried google but i can do it only in Activity not in slider menu or dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to change the transparency of the area of the screen over which the sliding drawer is open.

You can try this if the above is correct.

```
 <SlidingDrawer
 android:id="@+id/drawer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:handle="@+id/handle"
 android:content="@+id/content">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@id/handle"
     android:layout_width="88dip"
     android:layout_height="44dip" />

 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@id/content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:background="#AAFFFFFF" />

</SlidingDrawer>
```

By setting this, `android:background="#AAFFFFFF"`
We are changing the transparency of the color white(FFFFFF).

I hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for response but it sets whole activity's background. I'm just setting content part of the drawer's background as you said, is it normal?

Comment: I will find it much easier to help you if I were able to see the layout XML where you have made the changes.